# WebGrid constructor parameters are wrong

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webgrid

I cannot understand why do i have an error on my constructor line.
I try to create a class that containes a WebGrid and a Custom set of filters
here is the code

```
    public class FilterableWebGrid<T> : System.Web.Helpers.WebGrid
    {
        public System.Web.Helpers.WebGrid Grid { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<AbstractSearch> Filters { get; set; }
        private IEnumerable<T> m_GridData;

        public FilterableWebGrid(T Model)
        {
            Grid = new System.Web.Helpers.WebGrid(source: m_GridData);
        }

    }
```

and on this line `Grid = new System.Web.Helpers.WebGrid(source: m_GridData);`
I get an error:

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Web.Helpers.WebGrid.WebGrid(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, string, int, bool,
>   bool, string, string, string, string, string, string, string)' has
>   some invalid arguments

I am passing an `IEnumerable` to the constructor of the WebGrid so why do I get this error? al other properties have default values...

Any help would be appreciated..

**EDIT 1:**
So after more digging found this specific error:

> cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable

that i got after passing all parameters:

```
 Grid = new System.Web.Helpers.WebGrid(
            source: m_GridData,
            columnNames: null,
            defaultSort: null,
            rowsPerPage: 10,
            canPage: true,
            canSort: true,
            ajaxUpdateContainerId: null,
            ajaxUpdateCallback: null,
            fieldNamePrefix: null,
            pageFieldName: null,
            selectionFieldName: null,
            sortFieldName: null,
            sortDirectionFieldName: null);
```

and the error is for line `source: m_GridData`

now why is it that `IEnumerable<T>` cannot be converted to `IEnumerable<dynamic>`

Answer (score 0):

The `WebGrid` will require `IEnumerable` for the model

```
@model IEnumerable<.....>
```